# Will the click wheel iPod classic will work with the latest macOS Ventura?

Tags: macos, compatibility, ventura, ipod-classic

Hi does anyone know if the click wheel iPod classic will work with macOS Ventura? I love my click wheel Sixth generationiPod, And I’m worried if I upgrade to Ventura I will lose the capacity capacity to put new music my iPod. Thanks for any help!